# Can't install nodejs-dev: unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies, package-management

I need to install nodejs-dev package.
But `sudo apt-get install nodejs-dev` throws

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs-dev : Depends: nodejs (= 0.4.9-1ubuntu3) but 0.4.12-1chl1~natty1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So... What can I do about this error?
I run Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a PPA or have added a source that provides `0.4.12-1chl1~natty1`, which is for 11.04. You need to remove that PPA, do an update, and then try to install nodejs-dev again.

- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)